# laravel 5.5. union multiple database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, union

I have two table and two connections 
(mysql) works for one table - dbname_web
(mysqlShop) works for second table  - dbname_shop

all three query works fine but when i use union
first connection lost and shows only second connection from mysqlShop

laravel error is dbname_shop.News doesn't exist
it must be dbname_web.News

```
    $News = DB::connection('mysql')->table('News')->selectRaw("title_ge as name,  CONCAT('$news_url/', id) as url")
        ->where("title_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
        ->orWhere("full_text_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%");

    $Album = DB::connection('mysql')->table('Album')->selectRaw("title_ge as name,  CONCAT('$album_url/', id) as url")
        ->where("title_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
        ->orWhere("full_text_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%");

    $Products = DB::connection('mysqlShop')->table('Products')->selectRaw("title_ge as name,  CONCAT('$product_url/', id) as url")
        ->where("title_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
        ->orWhere("soft_id","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
        ->orWhere("full_text_ge","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%");


    $result = $Products->union($News)->union($Album)->get();


    return response()->json($result);
```

SQL output

```
(select title_ge as name,  CONCAT('http:\/\/nova.ge\/product\/item\/', id) as url from `Products` where `title_ge` LIKE ? or `soft_id` LIKE ? or `full_text_ge` LIKE ?) union (select title_ge as name,  CONCAT('http:\/\/nova.ge\/news\/', id) as url from `News` where `title_ge` LIKE ? or `full_text_ge` LIKE ?) union (select title_ge as name,  CONCAT('http:\/\/nova.ge\/album\/', id) as url from `Album` where `title_ge` LIKE ? or `full_text_ge` LIKE ?)
```

And Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;novage_shop.News&#039; doesn&#039;t exist (SQL: (select title_ge as name,  CONCAT(&#039;http://nova.ge/product/item/&#039;, id) as url from `Products` where `title_ge` LIKE %test search% or `soft_id` LIKE %test search% or `full_text_ge` LIKE %test search%) union (select title_ge as name,  CONCAT(&#039;http://nova.ge/news/&#039;, id) as url from `News` where `title_ge` LIKE %test search% or `full_text_ge` LIKE %test search%) union (select title_ge as name,  CONCAT(&#039;http://nova.ge/album/&#039;, id) as url from `Album` where `title_ge` LIKE %test search% or `full_text_ge` LIKE %test search%))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're not going to be able to use the connections to select the database/table like that when using a union. Instead, try `DB::raw('database_name.table_name')` for the table.

Comment: still have a problem